# How to deallocate memory that is allocated dynamically inside a function?

Tags: c++, function, memory, new-operator

If we allocate memeory by **new** in c++ we should deallocate them by using **delete** keyword. But i want to allocated memory dynamically inside a function and return it. The problem is if i deallocate the memory before i return it causes for a undefined behavior or something else :( how do i solve this problem!??? :)

```
int *fn()
{
    int *arr = new int[4]{1 ,4 ,9 ,16}; 
    //delete arr; arr = nullptr;
    //deleting before returning is causes undefined behavior :<
    return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *i = fn();
    delete[] i;

    int *j = fn();
    delete[] j;
    //delete[] doesn't solve the memory leak.
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

in above case **fn()** causes huge memory leak! How do i manage this memory leak without using `std::vector` or `struct` s

Comment: You solve it by not allocating or deallocating anything, but using containers, like `std::vector`, instead.

Comment: The above is perfectly OK. Allocate in function, return pointer, deallocate later.

Comment: the problem is you `delete` `new[]`ed memory, it's UB even in the function. (as point out by @heapunderrun below, OP actually did use array version but edit for some reason.)

Comment: The edit you've made invalidates the comments made before your edit.

Comment: @dilipIsharaSOF it's no true, `delete[]` doen't need original pointer variable, as long as they're equivalent. (before your edit, ofcourse)

Comment: @dilipIsharaSOF not sure where you got the information, `delete` doesn't touch(change) the variable at all.

Comment: @appleapple ok, i'll find further about memory deallocation! thanks for your support! :)

Comment: *How do i manage this memory leak without using std::vector or struct s* -- You're making a spaghetti-like mess with just a few lines of code that tries to manage `new` and `delete`.  Why not take the suggestion of throwing this away and use `std::vector` or containers, or smart pointers?  If this little bit of code causes all of these issues, imagine something more complex.

Comment: In C++, any dynamically-allocated memory being held by a raw pointer is a memory leak waiting to happen… ie even if the code is correct *now*, it’s likely that at some point a programmer will come along and modify the code in a way that unintentionally introduces a leak.  It’s much safer to hold and return dynamically allocated objects with a smart-pointer (or container) instead.

Comment: `int *j = fn();
    delete[] i;` of course it is a memory leak. You so often edited the question, so I think the shown code is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

> in above case `fn()` causes huge memory leak!

The entire program allocates a tiny amount of memory, so it's unclear what makes you consider the leak "huge".

> ```
> int *j = fn();
> int *j = fn();
>
> delete[] i;
> delete[] j;
> ```

There is a potential case where the first allocation can leak: if the second allocation fails and throws an exception. In that case the `delete[]` won't be executed. But you don't catch the exception, so it would cause the program to terminate, so the leak is less of a problem in that case.

> how do i solve this problem!???

Use `std::vector`.

> without using `std::vector`

Write your own implementation of dynamic array container.

Or, you could use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`.

---

After your edit:

> ```
> delete i;
> delete j;
> ```

With this change, the behaviour of the program is undefined. The immediate fix to the UB is to use `delete[]` instead. But that doesn't fix the leak in case of an exception. To fix that, use a container like `std::vector`.

---

After your edit:

> ```
> int *i = fn();
> delete[] j;
>
> int *j = fn();
> delete[] i;
> ```

Now you've flipped the order, and leak `j`.

If you were to fix the order, that would fix the potential memory leak of the earlier version. It's still quite brittle since it's easy to introduce memory leaks when expanding the example to be more complex. I would still recommend using a container.